# can't make links active when scrolling to a specific section in page

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm doing a landing page functionality with pure JavaScript and not allowed to use any libraries. I want to make a link on scroll to a specific section to be active. so I did a helper function `IsInViewPort()` to sense the position when I'm scrolling the page.

I'm trying to make a function that is on scrolling, Looping inside the sections in the page to add the specified section to the classList and make its link from navbar active. when I added this function there was an error says "unexpected identifier" and the navbar disappeared. How to fix it?
global variables:

```
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
const addToNav = document.querySelector('ul');
const myLinks = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
```

The helper function:

```
    const isInViewport = elem => {
  let distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    distance.top >= 0 &&
    distance.left >= 0 &&
    distance.bottom <=
      (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    distance.right <=
      (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
};
```

The function:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll" , e=>{
  for(let i=0 ; i<sections.length;i++){
    if(isInViewport(sections[i])){
      sections[i].classList.add("your-active-class");
      var activateLink = document.getElementsByClassName(''+[i]+'')[0];
      activateLink.classList.add("active");
    }
    else{
      sections[i].classList.remove("your-active-class");
      var activateLink = document.getElementsByClassName(''+[i]+'')[0];
      activateLink.classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
});
```

This is my project so far: https://jsfiddle.net/dode2/yqne0orj/1/
my issue in `//Set sections as active`.

Answer (score 0):

The "unexpected identifier" is caused by your "int i=0" which should be let i=0

The following code:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll" , e=>{
for(int i=0 ; i<=sections.length;i++){
    if(isInViewport(sections[i])){
        sections[i].classList.add("your-active-class");
        document.getElementsByClassName(`${sections[i].id}`)[0].classList.add("active");
    }
    else{
        section.classList.remove("your-active-class");
        document.getElementsByClassName(`${sections[i].id}`)[0].classList.remove("active");
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll" , e=>{
for(let i=0 ; i<=sections.length;i++){
    if(isInViewport(sections[i])){
        sections[i].classList.add("your-active-class");
        document.getElementsByClassName(`${sections[i].id}`)[0].classList.add("active");
    }
    else{
        section.classList.remove("your-active-class");
        document.getElementsByClassName(`${sections[i].id}`)[0].classList.remove("active");
    }
}
```

That will fix your error.

Comment: Hi el3ati2, the navbar still disappears and another error popped up says "Unexpected end of input".